# Given a function and how do you determine the pdf of the left side given the pdf of the right side variables?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Given a function and how do you determine the pdf of the left side given the pdf of the right side variables? Specifically what is the pdf of W, given the equation
$$
W = I^2 R$$
with $I$ and $R$ are independent random variables and their pdfs given by,
$$
\begin{align}
f_I (x) &= 
\begin{cases}
6x(1-x) & \text{if }  0 \le x \le 1  \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \\
f_R (r) &= 
\begin{cases}
2r & \text{if }  0 \le r \le 1  \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You can't determine the distribution of $W$ based on the marginal distributions of $I$ and $R$ _unless_ you assume independence. If you don't assume independence, then you need to know the joint distribution (or density) of $(I,R)$.

Comment: @StefanHansen, I am assuming $I$ and $R$ are independent random variables

Comment: Something is not right. Both $f_I$ and $f_R$ are not densities because they do not integrate to 1.

Comment: @StefanHansen, pdfs updated with correct values

Comment: I think the title of the problem has nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: @Tunococ I changed the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the cdf of $W$: for a fixed $w \in [0, 1]$,
\begin{align}
\Pr(W \le w)
& = \Pr(I^2R \le w) \\
& = \Pr(I^2 \le w/R) \\
& = \int_0^1 \Pr(I^2 \le w/R \mid R = r) f_R(r) dr \\
& = \int_0^1 \Pr\left(I \le \sqrt{w/r}\right) f_R(r) dr \\
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{w/r}} f_I(i)f_R(r)\ di\ dr.
\end{align}
Differentiate with respect to $w$ to get
\begin{align}
f_W(w) & =
\int_0^1 \frac 1{2\sqrt{wr}}f_I\left(\sqrt{w/r}\right)f_R(r) dr \\
& = \int_w^1 \frac 1{2\sqrt{wr}} \cdot 6 \sqrt{w/r}\left(1 - \sqrt{w/r}\right)
\cdot 2r\ dr \\
& = 6 \int_w^1 \left(1 - \sqrt{w/r}\right) dr\\
& = 6\left.\left(r - 2\sqrt{wr}\right)\right|_{r=w}^1 \\
& = 6\left(1 - 2\sqrt w - w + 2w\right) \\
& = 6\left(1 - 2\sqrt w + w\right).
\end{align}

Comment: I can follow most of this. But where does $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{wr}}$ come from? And why $\int_w^1$?

Comment: $\frac 1{2\sqrt{wr}} f_I\left(\sqrt{w/r}\right)$ is the result from the fundamental theorem of calculus. The change from $\int_0^1$ to $\int_w^1$ happens because $f_I\left(\sqrt{w/r}\right) = 0$ when $\sqrt{w/r} \ge 1$, which is equivalent to $w \ge r$, so we can discard the part $\int_0^w$.